# jQuery Ajax Cross Origin Issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

We are making Ajax request from server1.corp.xyz.com to server2.corp.xyz.com and still getting Cross-Origin error. Is it a valid case for Cross-Origin or am i missing something. What could be the possible solution.

Comment: Yes. That is the valid error.

Comment: I used it as an answer, but then I realized you also want a solution for that problem, while I work it out - here's a quick explanation:
It is considered a different host: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Comment: if you own `server2.corp.xyz.com` then an easy solution is to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in that domain

Answer (score 2):

> What could be the possible solution.

You can enable [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) on your server2.corp.xyz.com server, to allow requests from your server1.corp.xyz.com server. Then the request will work on nearly any [CORS-enabled browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors). I say "nearly" because you've said you're using jQuery, and bizarrely (in my view), jQuery doesn't work around a browser incompatibility in this regard like it does so many others: IE8 and IE9 support CORS, but they don't support it via the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object; you have to use the `XDomainRequest` object instead. (Microsoft gets it right starting with IE10.) So to have the cross-origin request work on IE8 or IE9, you need to either use `XDomainRequest` directly yourself instead of using jQuery's `ajax`, or you need to find and use a patch/plugin to jQuery that adds support for IE8 and 9 (I understand there are some, but I don't have a specific one to recommend).

Answer (score 2):

You can set origins with htacess in your folder

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Or search in Google how to set origins. I prefer to set origin only for server1.corp.xyz.com domain.
You can set in apache too.

Comment: Where can i set origins with htacess on server1 or server2.

Comment: You must create .htacess on server2. The main goal is to access Ajax request from server1 to server2.

Comment: I have Tomcat installed on Server 2 and i believe i wont be allowed to do any modifications there. So looks like i can only go the curl route?

Comment: You must start with this. Did you check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter I think this is for Tomcat :)

Comment: Alternative is to use JSONP with callback - but I'm not 100% how to use it.